# Values from table with variables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm

A table R(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6) it has 6 columns with natural numbers
(0,1,2,3,..)

```
R
-----------------------------
A1| A2 |A3 |A4 | A5 |A6
0 | 1  | 0 |  1| 1  |0
1 | 0  | 0 | 1 | 0  |0
0 | 0  | 0 | K  |0  |0
0 | 0  | 1 |0  | 1  |0
0 | 1  | 1 | 1 | 1  |0
1 | 1  |1  | 1 | 0  |1
1 | 1  | 1 | 1 | 0  |1
1 | 1  | 1 | 0 | M  |1
1|  1  | 0 |1  | 1  |0
0 | 1  |0  |1  | 0  |0
1 | 1  | 0 |0  | 0  |0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN3yE.jpg)

**Question** : For what values K and M the execution of the code SQL calculates/produce result (SUM(d),SUM(e)) the couple of values(15,22)?

Information:I really no idea how can I solve an exercise like this.Can someone answer this question?I have searched everywhere but nothing similar to it. I want to understand the mindset of it. Please someone if can help with it.

Comment: This is not really appropriate as a SQL query.  Moreover, if the values are numbers, you cannot represent this as a table, so I'm a little confused on what your data looks like.  And `d` and `e` are not defined.

Comment: I think it's called "functional relationships". d and e are definied on the image.I beleive the variables K and M are numbers

Comment: Please replace the image with text in a code block.

Comment: This seems more like a math problem than SQL. SQL is just being used to represent the mathematical relationships between the values in the matrix.

Comment: Yes, but without SQL knowledge, there is no hope of doing this dude's homework for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K = 11
M = 17

**R1**
`GROUP BY R.A6` means you're looking at two groups (0 or 1).
`HAVING SUM(R.A3)>2` means you only want the group where the sum of R.A3 within that group is greater than 2.
So, you're only looking at the rows where A6 = 1.
d = `COUNT(R.A4)` = 3 (the number of rows where A6 = 1)
e = `2+SUM(R.A5)` = 2 + M

**R2**
`GROUP BY R.A2` means you are looking at two groups (0 or 1).
`HAVING SUM(R.A1)<3` means you only want the group where the sum of R.A1 within the group is less than 3.
So, you're only looking at the rows where A2 = 0.
d = `SUM(R.A4)` = 1 + K
e = `COUNT(R.A5` = 3 (the number of rows where A2 = 0)

**R3**
The union simply appends the rows from R2 to the rows from R1.

So,

```
SELECT SUM(d), SUM(e)
FROM R3
```

...produces 4+K and 5+M.