# Group by and having count weird

Tags: sql, database

[I have this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0UN6.jpg)

```
R1(a,b,c,d,e,f)
AS
(
  SELECT MIN(R.A1),MAX(R.A2),1, COUNT(R.A4),2+SUM(R.A5),0
  FROM R
  GROUP BY R.A6
  HAVING SUM(R.A3)>2
),

R2(a,b,c,d,e,f)
AS
(
  SELECT 1,0, MAX(R.A3),SUM(R.A4), COUNT(R.A5),2+SUM(R.A6)
  FROM R
  GROUP BY R.A2
  HAVING SUM(R.A1)<3
),

R3 AS 
(
  SELECT *FROM R1 UNINON SELECT * FROM R2
)
SELECT SUM(d),SUM(e)
FROM R3
```

based on  this sql code

Question:What is the product X,Y that gives result (11,11)?

What I did is :

from **R1**
**I have COUNT(R.A4) it makes   3+X** ???

```
  2+SUM(R.A5) it makes 2 + Y
```

From **R2**

```
SUM(R.A4) = 1+X

COUNT(R.A5)=8+Y
```

So,

```
SELECT SUM(d), SUM(e)
FROM R3
```

produces 4+X and 8+Y.

what I found is ,x=7 and Y=3 so I will have (11,11) I am not sure

I am feeling something I am doing wrong...

editted more:
what i think is-not sure
GROUP BY R.A2
HAVING SUM(R.A1)<3  // I go to A1 and look 0 + 0 = 0 it is smaller than the 3 so I take the results 0 from A1 which are 0 from the table A2.As a result I have 2 rows COUNT(R.A5)=2+Y.

Comment: That table does not make sense -- it looks like a boolean value and then randomly has an X and Y

Comment: @Hogan it is similar exercise like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568027/values-from-table-with-variables?fbclid=IwAR2NaSRAhtgUoeI6MhCek-PUtIos94tK2sG-_cvC656jxzXk01Pv1K_PXt8

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is just asking us to solve a test problem

Comment: @Hogan I don't care about to solve it man.I want to understand  this line : GROUP BY R.A2 HAVING SUM(R.A1)<3 . I don't get it. Can you explain me? R.A2 it means I go to A2 and I have 1 or 2. Now,the having sum(R.A1) which is smaller than 3 I don't undertand what should I look at .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a select statement containing a GROUP BY the WHERE clause will filter what rows get processed by the GROUP BY.  The HAVING clause will filter what records are returned by the query.

So `GROUP BY R.A2 HAVING SUM(R.A1)<3` will perform a GROUP BY on the distinct values of R.A2 and then if the SUM of the values in the A1 column are greater than or equal to 3 they will not be returned in the results.

Comment: If I got it you tell me that A1 values the sum of each row  0+1+1+1+1+0+1  the sum of it is 5. 5 <3 so the 5 will not returned? with other words it will not been executed and the union in R3 right? so it is wrong the sum on the A2 ?

Comment: @maiklkof  No.  This is a group by.  group by means it groups by.  So the group by will return to rows -- one grouped by A2 = 1 and one grouped by A2 = 2.  Then for each of those groups it will sum the values of the A1 column.  If that sum is 3 or more it won't be returned.

Comment: group by A2 1 or 2 ok it is clear this. So I must look A2 column   and A1 column. Group lets call it A2=1 I have in A1 I have sum 4 (if I add the 1+1+1+1) so this group fails. Now the Group A2=2 I have in A1 I have the sum 2 and yes is smaller than 3. I got it right?

Comment: @maiklkof - yes